# Best design for handling multi-level events

Tags: events, architecture, event-handling, microservices

I have 4 entities:

- `Mall` contains multiple `Shop` subobjects
- `Shop` contains multiple `Basket` subobjects
- `Basket` contains multiple `Fruit` subobjects.
- `Fruit` which is a leaf subobject.

[image]

`updateMall(...)` calls `updateShop(...)`, which calls `updateBasket(...)`, which calls `updateFruit(...)`.

Each of these `updateXxx(...)` function sends a `XxxUpdatedEvent` once it is done.

Therefore, if `updateMall(...)` is called, there will be many event sent: `FruitUpdatedEvent`, `BasketUpdatedEvent`, `ShopUpdatedEvent`, `MallUpdatedEvent`.

This granularity of event is desirable because some event listeners may only care about e.g. `BasketUpdatedEvent` and not necessarily about parent-data event.

Here is a sequence diagram of 2 producers and 2 listeners:

[image]

As you can see, `Listener2` needs to keep all data in sync with its own internal business logic. Therefore it needs to listen to everything. It cannot only listen to `MallUpdatedEvent`, because sometimes only `FruitUpdatedEvent` will be emitted.

*(In my real life scenario, this `Listener2` is a ElasticSearch index, trying to keep up with the changed data).*

The issue here is, as you can see, the redundancy of the nested synchronization. The sub-object synchronisation methods are called more than needed to do the same job over and over.

I am pretty sure this design issue is common, and people had to address it over and over, but unfortunately my googling efforts didn't pay off.
What is a good design pattern to address this issue in a efficient, granular and elegant way?

I've thought of some debouncing mechanism, but it is not bulletproof.

Comment: It sounds like a CRUD approach to something that follows a business process. The Mall, Shop, and Fruit are CRUD objects in a store. I think the real business events are within the order object. Should you rethink the emitted events and the value of them?

Comment: Are you the owner of the emitted events? In other words can you change the "shape"/schema of the events or they are written in stone from your perspective.

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes I can choose any event shape/payload. The sky is the limit.

Comment: So, in this case could your higher level event include data about lower level entities? Like the aggregate root concept

Comment: @PeterCsala Are you suggesting to only send `MallUpdatedEvent` even for small fruit updates ? I cannot figure out how I can avoid the waste of synchronizing the whole mall just to pick up the one fruit that was changed.

Comment: @OoDeLally Yes, if have a single event which contains hierarchical data then according to my understanding you would only need to wait for that event rather than have a synchronisation logic to receive all four.

Comment: @OoDeLally But as always it depends on couple of factors: the 3 Vs (Volume, Velocity, Variety), the number of consumers, the consistency model of the system, etc.

Comment: @PeterCsala I see some issue in that model, coming from the fact that not every element is aware of what's a `Mall`. Some elements only know `Fruit`, and it's against SoC principle to "force" all elements to know about the whole hierarchy, when they only care about `Fruit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it appears that you can design your system to maintain the following invariants and that you probably already did:

1. `updateFruit` is the *only* place in your logic where fruits may be altered.
2. `updateFruit` *always* triggers the `FruitUpdatedEvent`.

Likewise for the other entity types. `updateBasket` might add, remove or perhaps reorder the fruits associated with a basket, but changes to the fruits themselves would be deferred to `updateFruit`.

Under these invariants, `costlyBasketSynchronize` does **not** need to call `costlyFruitSynchronize`. After all, if any of the fruits in the basket was modified along with the basket itself, then the `FruitUpdatedEvent` has already been triggered and handled. This principle extends to the higher levels of nesting as well.

[Backbone](https://backbonejs.org), a client side framework for JavaScript, has been successfully following this principle since 2010. It has a similar hierarchy, but with only two levels. The smaller entity is called `Model` and the larger, containing one is called `Collection`.

`Model` has a `set` method to update its attributes. If any of the attributes change value, the model triggers a `change` event.

`Collection` also has a `set` method, to update its models. This might add, remove or reorder models associated with the collection. In addition, it recursively calls the `set` method of each model to update its attributes, which in turn might trigger `change` events. The collection itself triggers a single `update` event at the end, regardless of whether any of the models in it have changed attributes or not.

A listener interested in both levels of the datastructure simply subscribes both to the `change` and the `update` events. The `change` listener handles model attribute changes while the `update` listener handles collection composition changes. It is a very clean separation of concerns and there is no redundancy in the system.